# Select and deselect all chips inside ChipGroup programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, material-components-android, android-chips

I have a chip group and inside that I am adding Choice Chips programmatically and I have a button called Select All for selecting all if some of them selected and Same Button for Deselecting All chips in a single click.

Now Please guide me some proper way or It would be great if it can be done using chip group instead of ArrayList of chip
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7):

For deselecting you can use [clearCheck](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup#clearCheck()) and for selection you've to go through for loop

Comment: Yes, It Helps me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I have created a general Extension function for the above solution in kotlin
I think that this is the proper solution

```
fun ChipGroup.applyCheckedOnAll(isChecked: Boolean){
    if (isChecked){
        for (index in 0 until this.childCount) {
            val chip:Chip = this.getChildAt(index) as Chip
            chip.isChecked = true
        }
    }else {
        this.clearCheck()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ChipGroup chipGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.chipGroup );
for (int i = 0; i < chipGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Chip chip = (Chip) chipGroup.getChildAt(i);
    chip.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: I feel like if have set of chips under chipGroup then better solution is calling clearCheck() method of chipGroup in order to unselectAll on tap of single button.

Answer (score 0):

Clears the selection. When the selection is cleared, no chip in this group is selected
chipgroup.clearCheck()